# Under what conditions can a Child of the Watch not wear their helmet?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian, mandalorian

With the helmet never being removed being one of the biggest trademarks of Din Djarin, we've found out that the *Children of the Watch* never remove their helmet. This, as it is stated such in the *Way of the Mandalore*.

> The cult's ideology stated that if a Mandalorian removed their helmet in front of another living being, they were no longer permitted to wear it.
>
> From the Star Wars Fandom article on [Way of the Mandalore](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Way_of_the_Mandalore)

But this is rather cumbersome at home, e.g. with ones spouse. So, when does a Child of the Watch receive their helmet and under what conditions are they allowed to remove it? And who is allowed to determine if this is / was an allowed removal of the helmet or not?

Canon answers preferred. If no canon answer is available, Legends is also accepted.

Comment: "But this is rather cumbersome at home, e.g. with ones spouse." Oh, the image you have painted in my head...

Comment: @VienLa Meh, there's a story, with this motif, but a man has to *kill* himself or his lover, after she saw his face! Now *that* showcases how dumb this trope is :D

Comment: I'm pretty sure that they can take it off when they're alone, so taking a bath or eating, but when they're eating they can't show their face, just enough for them to consume the food. And I believe that they can take it off in front of spouses of children, someone very close to them, like immediate family.

Comment: @Hello That would be logical, yes. But we need sources for this...

Comment: Well I can find sources for the first two, but not if they are allowed to take it off in front of close family.

Comment: If Children of the Watch's rigid helmet requirement doesn't cause serious, fatal, skin infections, then that means that every Mandalorian is immune to the effects of microorganisms ravaging the flesh that is contained under their helmets. It's also interesting that the grown male Mandalorian Children of the Watch don't have long, bushy beards protruding from under their helmets, since they can never remove these helmets for any reason.

Comment: @FrankRendar Din removes the helmet, when he's in private, i.e. nobody sees him. However, when he is in public, he's wearing the helmet. There are therefore ample possibilites to shave. Plus, the helmet might have a hygiene function...

Comment: @Shade If the helmet has a hygiene function and/or blades inside that shave Din's face, then we should have seen it. Din's helmet appears to have basic helmet construction. The Children of the Watch have bizarre beliefs that "demand" that all adherents keep their helmets on for life.